# Read context-param in CDI bean returns null

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, wildfly

I'm trying to read a context-param property contained in web.xml from a CDI Bean Application scoped. Unfortunately a null is returned.

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Named
public class Utils  {
   public String getUpdateFile() {
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();    
         return ctx.getExternalContext().getInitParameter("update.file");
   }
}
```

And web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>update.file</param-name>
        <param-value>update.zip</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Is it my mistake ? any workaround ? My environment is WildFly 8.1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just inject the **Servlet Context**. The ServletContext is made available as an application-scoped bean. It can be injected safetly into any CDI bean as follows:

```
@Inject   
private ServletContext context;

public String getUpdateFile() {

         return context.getInitParameter("update.file");
}
```

Coded a mini [tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/cdi/accessing-servletcontext-and-servletrequest-in-cdi-beans) here.